# when i add a package i recieve webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.This is no longer the case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix, babel-polyfill

i use react with laravel. i install a date picker package with nmp and after install that when i start npm run watch i recieved this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/poldark/Desktop/chapagha/chapagha/src/chapagha-web/node_modules/jalali-react-datepicker/dist'

> webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

and

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

can any one tell me what to do?

Answer (score -1):

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    resolve: {
      // 如果确认需要node polyfill，设置resolve.fallback安装对应的依赖
      fallback: {
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
        path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
        url: require.resolve('url'),
        buffer: require.resolve('buffer/'),
        util: require.resolve('util/'),
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify/'),
        vm: require.resolve('vm-browserify')
      },
      // 如果确认不需要node polyfill，设置resolve.alias设置为false
      alias: {
        crypto: false
      }
    }
}
```